# Invalid modifier, modifier must be an object Error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to update a record from the client but keep getting an error. Tried putting everything into a `data = {}` object and passing it to my `Meteor.call` method, but still couldn't get it to work.

**browser**: `errorClass {error: 500, reason: "Internal server error", details: undefined, message: "Internal server error [500]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}`

**server**: `Exception while invoking method 'updateComment' Error: Invalid modifier. Modifier must be an object.`

I know it has to do with how I'm calling my `updateComment` method. Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Current code:

**comments/methods.js**

```
updateComment: function (commentId, commentContent, userId, fritkotId) {
    // check(commentId, String);
    // check(commentContent, String);
    // check(userId, String);
    // check(firtkotId, String);
    Comments.update({
            _id: commentId,
            body: commentContent,
            author: userId,
            fritkotId: fritkotId,
            modifiedAt: new Date()
        });
}....
```

**editComment.js**

```
import './editComment.tpl.jade'

// Events
Template.editComment.events({
'click .form-save': (e)  => {

    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {};

    let commentContent = $('.update-comment').val();

    let fritkotId =  Fritkots.findOne({})._id;
    let commentId = Comments.findOne({})._id;
    let userId =  Meteor.userId();

    // data.commentId = commentId;
    // data.commentContent = commentContent;
    // data.userId = userId;
    // data.fritkotId = fritkotId;

    console.log(` This is the commentId: ${commentId}, userId: ${userId}, fritkotId: ${fritkotId}`);

    Meteor.call('updateComment', commentId, commentContent, userId, fritkotId, function(error) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('comment updated');
        } else {
            console.log(error);
            console.log('unable to update comment');
        }
    })

    console.log(`The comment was updated to this ${commentContent}`);

    console.log('I was clicked for save');

    // Session.set('editCommentId', false);
    Session.set('editCommentId', null);
},
....
```

**collections/comments.js**

```
Comments = new Mongo.Collection('comments')

// Permissions
Comments.allow({
    insert: () => false,
    // update: (userId, doc) => { return !! userId; },
    update: () => false,
    remove: () => false
});

Comments.deny({
    insert: () => true,
    update: () => true,
    // update: (userId, doc) => { return !! userId; },
    remove: () => true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a way to identify the comment, then pass in the parts you want to change. There's definitely a problem in the use of the .update() (check documentation).

I believe you want something like this:

```
Comments.update(id, {$set: {key: value}})
```

or this

```
Comments.update(id, {$set: {key: value}})
```